# Display a count of records within 15 miles of a subscriber ZIP code

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, geolocation, count

I have an ExactTarget question.

I have a data extension of `_subscribers`.  One of the fields is their `zip_code`
I have another data extension of _widgets which includes the widgets' `zip_code1`
I also have a data extension with the fields: `zip, latitude, longitude`

In the body of an email, I'd like to to tell the recipient how many widgets are located within 25 kilometers of their ZIP code.

> "There are [number] widgets near you!"

I could really use some help on how this should be set up.  Anyone ever done anything like this?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: In your question, are you looking for the logic to set up the 25k calculation?  Or do you already have something you are trying to implement within ET?

Answer (score 0):

It will probably take some adjustments to the data model you have in mind, but there is a query located on this page, in bottom (link: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) that has an example of a SQL query you can leverage/incorporate into your process to output another column with the desired value, and then use in your email.